# Grouping by multiple variables in R - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

The following code comes from: 
R for Data Science, 5.6.5 Grouping by multiple variables.

My question is: What is the process `R` is going through or what is R doing at each step to reduce down to the final 1x2 tibble?

I think I understand the first couple of assignments: 
`'daily'` is sorting the `'flights'` data frame by year then month then day.
`'per_day'` creates 3 columns of `'year'`, `'month'`, `'day'`, and a final fourth `'flights'` column counting the number of flights on said day of the month of year.

However from `'per_month'` on is where I begin to understand how the function is being evaluated.

For example, in the per_month tibble, what is happening that R knows to take only the flights from year 2013, month 1 to sum, rather than just adding the entire flights  column and eliminating the day column?

Thanks!

```
daily <- group_by(flights, year, month, day)

(per_day   <- summarise(daily, flights = n()))
#> # A tibble: 365 x 4
#> # Groups:   year, month [?]
#>    year month   day flights
#>   <int> <int> <int>   <int>
#> 1  2013     1     1     842
#> 2  2013     1     2     943
#> 3  2013     1     3     914
#> 4  2013     1     4     915
#> 5  2013     1     5     720
#> 6  2013     1     6     832
#> # … with 359 more rows

(per_month <- summarise(per_day, flights = sum(flights)))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   year [?]
#>    year month flights
#>   <int> <int>   <int>
#> 1  2013     1   27004
#> 2  2013     2   24951
#> 3  2013     3   28834
#> 4  2013     4   28330
#> 5  2013     5   28796
#> 6  2013     6   28243
#> # … with 6 more rows

(per_year  <- summarise(per_month, flights = sum(flights)))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    year flights
#>   <int>   <int>
#> 1  2013  336776
```

Comment: I vote to close this question as it is not really a coding question; you seem to ask for general tutorial advice/explanations on basic `tidyverse` functions, and a good `tidyverse`/`dplyr` tutorial will be a much better source of information here that SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` adds a class and adds a group attribute, then each summarize call peels of a group while data is aggregated by for each distinct combination of grouping variables. When the all the groups are peeled off the `tibble` loses its `grouped_df` class.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(nycflights13)

names(attributes(flights))
#> [1] "names"     "row.names" "class"
class(flights)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
groups(flights)
#> NULL

daily <- group_by(flights, year, month, day)
names(attributes(daily))
#> [1] "names"     "row.names" "class"     "groups"
class(daily)
#> [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
groups(daily)
#> [[1]]
#> year
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> month
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> day

per_day   <- summarise(daily, flights = n())
names(attributes(per_day))
#> [1] "names"     "row.names" "class"     "groups"
class(per_day)
#> [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
groups(per_day)
#> [[1]]
#> year
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> month

per_month <- summarise(per_day, flights = sum(flights))
class(per_month)
#> [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
groups(per_month)
#> [[1]]
#> year

per_year  <- summarise(per_month, flights = sum(flights))
class(per_year)
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
groups(per_year)
#> NULL
```

Comment: Ok, that makes much more sense now. Thank you so much for the explanation, I really appreciate it!